# Copy properties of object to another skipping undefined ones

Tags: javascript

How can I copy a list of properties from a object to another skipping the null or undefined values?

Something like this

```js
const obj1 = { prop1: 'value', prop2: undefined }

const obj2 = copy(obj1, ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3']) // prop3 doesn't exist and prop2 should be excluded

console.log(obj2) // should print { prop1: 'value' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const obj1 = { prop1: 'value', prop2: undefined }

function copy(obj1, props)
{
  return props.reduce(
    (acum, current) => 
      (obj1[current] !== undefined && obj1[current] !== null) ? 
        ({...acum, [current]:obj1[current]}):
        acum
    ,{}
  )
}

const obj2 = copy(obj1, ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3']) // prop3 doesn't exist and prop2 should be excluded

console.log(obj2) // should print { prop1: 'value' }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

see: [`Object.fromEntries(): Object transformations`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#object_transformations)

```js
const obj1 = { prop1: 'value', prop2: undefined }

const copy = (obj, props) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([k, v]) => (
      (props.includes(k) && v !== undefined && v !== null)
    )));
}

const obj2 = copy(obj1, ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3'])

console.log(obj2)
```

Comment: Just realized, editing. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

```
function copy(object, keys) {
  const clone = {};    
  for(const key of keys) {
    if(!isNaN(object[key])) clone[key] = object[key];
  }
  return clone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what the purpose of the array is in your code, but this should work for the problem as you stated it. It reduces over the entries of the original object with a new object as an accumulator, and only copies over properties with defined values. To include null in the check, you can change the condition to be `!= null` (because `undefined == null`).

```js
const copyExcludingUndefined = (obj = {}) =>
  Object.entries(obj)
    .reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
      if (v !== undefined) {
        a[k] = v
      }
      return a
    }, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your own copy function :)

```
let copy = function(o, args) {
    let obj = {};
    if (Array.isArray(args)) {
        args.forEach(arg => {
            if(o[arg] !== undefined) {
                obj[arg] = o[arg];
            }    
        });
    }

    return obj;
}
```